# Randomly my server json response have crazy values

Tags: php, json

I'm building the API for my website (php).
Everything is working fine, i test the responses and my json(s) and everywhing is okay.

BUT. Sometimes, in my app (iOS) when parsing the json I obtain crazy value.
I checked everything, and in theory (and when I try with my computer) everything is working fine, even during most of the times with my app, but, again, sometims, a corrupted json land on my phone...

Why is that?
How can I fix the json? or make sure it stays intact?

Thanks
(sorry for my English, Italian here)

Comment: Define "crazy value". Is it no longer JSON? Or is it a valid JSON with nonsense values inside? What is the size of the JSON packet and how is it generated?

Comment: You should provide whatever code you use to generate that JSON, and also a sample of the "crazy values".

Comment: It is no longer Json :S
Just a bunch of random letters and numbers

Comment: Try *compressing* those letters and numbers with gzip, if possible. If you discover that the resulting output is approximately as long as the input, that's a very good indication that you're receiving garbled compressed data. This can happen sometimes with some mobile operators. Try completely disabling zlib, gzhandler (in PHP) and DEFLATE support (in Apache). **IF** this solves the problem, you can pursue a more sophisticated approach based on user-agent and remote host address (i.e. you only disable compression for IP ranges of mobile operators that are notoriously *sfigati*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that PHP emits warnings or errors in the output. Which you should also be able to see in the webservers error log.